# Streaming in Higher Order Functions (map, filter etc.) in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4, higher-order-functions

I've already gone through multiple posts regarding how **higher order functions** - `filter, map, sort, reduce` etc. work in **Swift**.

What I want to know is the internal working of these methods. Do they use **streaming** to produce the final output?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

var arr1 = arr.map { $0 * $0 }.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 } //Output: [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

What I mean is, in the above code, every time `map` processes an element from `arr`, will it be passed on to `filter` without waiting for the `map` to process all the elements in `arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, they don't. `filter` is only run when `map` is completed when used normally.

You can however optimize it better by declaring the collection `lazy` wherein your filtering will only happen when there is need for it from the next function in the chain. This also prevents the creation of *intermediate* arrays. (Every function will create a *new* array otherwise, which will then be passed to the next function)

---

Check this out for a really good explanation about lazy collections. - [Lazy Collections in Swift](https://medium.com/developermind/lightning-read-1-lazy-collections-in-swift-fa997564c1a3)

Comment: Isn't the execution same as streaming?

Comment: @PGDev If by streaming you mean the last paragraph in your question. Then no. The article has an example showing how they are executed.

Comment: By streaming I mean - `1. We iterate only once.
2. We get each element calculated through the pipe as we access them.`

Comment: @PGDev i believe that is what would happen if you make the collection lazy at every point. Atleast that is what i understood from that article. Unfortunately, i do not have any experience working on it. I just read about it and it made sense and i thought this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: @PGDev It seems that the article has the exact lines that you said near the end. I just re-read it now. :) `If we do use lazy;

We iterate only once.
We get each element calculated through the pipe as we access them.`

Comment: Yes, I copied these lines from the article itself.